Chrome Update disables extension - how to keep it enabled?
At the company I work for we use a 3rd-party Chrome extension for automation of web tests. Whenever a Chrome update is rolled out, the extension gets disabled and we have to manually enable it again. This is feasible for a small number of machines but is impractical for the number of machines we want to run automation on.
Is there a setting or policy that regulates whether extensions stay enabled or not after an update? I checked the Chrome policies, settings, and flags but could not find something fitting. Disabling or delaying Chrome updates is not an option for us.

Yes, you can download the Google Chrome GPO and import it in to Group Policy, then manage the allowed extensions and even force certain extensions on.
